# little error for a newbie in Javascript MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, javascriptmvc

Hi I am just starting a tutorial in javascriptMVC (JqueryMX) I have an error "Uncaught type error Cannot call method 'Model' of undefined" I have checked all path and don't understand why it is still not working. Any help will be greatfull. todo.js below

```
steal('jquerypp/class',
  'jquerypp/controller',
  'jquerypp/model',
  'jquerypp/view/ejs',
  'jquerypp/dom/fixture',

function($){
$.Model('Todo',
{
findAll : "GET /todos",
findOne : "GET /todos/{id}",
create  : "POST /todos",
update  : "PUT /todos/{id}",
destroy : "DELETE /todos/{id}"
},{})
});
```

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <ul id='todos'></ul>
  <input id='editor'/>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='../steal/steal.js?todos/todos.js'></script>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: did you load jquery properly?

Comment: The problem is from Jquery, but where to insert it in the steal controler or the html file ?

Answer (score 0):

did you have this solved already?
if not, i would suggest that you try the JMVC code generator (./js jmvc/generate/app myapp) as seen in here --> http://javascriptmvc.com/, there you will see how the libraries are placed.

and by the way, the steal.js should be placed in the html file, all others can be in the main js file.